# What is the T-SQl syntax to transform data from a single table into this specific format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, syntax, unpivot

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have a table in my database called MyTable. Extract of which is shown below:

```
Hotel   Market    Desc    Jan16      Feb16       
ABC     France    SUP HB   158        33       
ABC     France    SUP AI    35         6       
ABC     France    DLX HB    27        10
```

I need to transform this table so that my SQL query output is as follows:

```
Hotel    Market   Desc      Date      Values
ABC      France   SUP HB    Jan16      158
ABC      France   SUP HB    Feb16       33
ABC      France   SUP AI    Jan16       35
ABC      France   SUP AI    Feb16        6
ABC      France   DLX HB    Jan16       27
ABC      France   DLX HB    Feb16       10
```

How can I achieve this output with T-SQL? After reading a bit on the problem on the web, I believe the UNPIVOT syntax might do the trick but I am at a total loss on how to use it in this context.

Comment: Agree. I have corrected my selection. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  *
from    mytable unpivot ("values" for "date" in (Jan16,Feb16)) u
```

---

```
+-------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| Hotel | Market | Desc   | values | date  |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| ABC   | France | SUP HB | 158    | Jan16 |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| ABC   | France | SUP HB | 33     | Feb16 |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| ABC   | France | SUP AI | 35     | Jan16 |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| ABC   | France | SUP AI | 6      | Feb16 |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| ABC   | France | DLX HB | 27     | Jan16 |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| ABC   | France | DLX HB | 10     | Feb16 |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select  Hotel  ,  Market,[desc],marks,Date 
from #c s
unpivot
(
  marks
  for date in (jan16, feb16)
) u;
```

or
2)

```
SELECT  HOTEL ,MARKET,A.[DESC] MARKET,[DATE] ,V.[DESC]
FROM   #C A
       CROSS APPLY (VALUES('JAN16', JAN16),
                          ('FEB16', FEB16))
                       V   (DATE, [DESC]); 
output

Hotel   Market  desc    marks   Date
ABC France  SUP HB  158 Jan16
ABC France  SUP HB  33  Feb16
ABC France  SUP AI  35  Jan16
ABC France  SUP AI  6   Feb16
ABC France  DLX HB  27  Jan16
ABC France  DLX HB  10  Feb16
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way would be to use a `UNION`:

```
SELECT Hotel, Market, Desc, 'Jan16' AS Date, Jan16 AS Values
FROM MyTable
UNION ALL
SELECT Hotel, Market, Desc, 'Feb16', Feb16
FROM MyTable
```

If you expect something more complex than this, e.g. more than two columns, then you can try using `UNPIVOT`.